# My system.webServer > staticContent > clientCache element obstructs serving CSS, JavaScript, and Images

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, web-config, static-content

I have this system.webServer section. When I add the **clientCache** line, the web server stops serving JavaScript, CSS, and images. When I remove the clientCache line, it again starts serving them. What is wrong with my clientCache element?

This problem occurs both in the Visual Studio development server and when I push the Website to Azure.

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="86400"/>
    </staticContent>
    <!--Handlers removed for clarity-->
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ASP.NET, the [clientCache](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/staticcontent/clientcache) > cacheControlMaxAge property is a **timespan** (though the [HTTP specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.3) makes its max-age header **seconds**.)

So, this is **wrong**:

```
<clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="86400"/>
```

And this is **right**:

```
<clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="1.00:00:00"/>
```

Where was the [ISO](http://www.iso.org/iso/home.html) on this one?